# How to pass parameters for a specific Schema registry when using Kafka Avro Console Consumer?

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I am trying to use Confluent `kafka-avro-console-consumer`, but how to pass parameters for Schema Registry to it?

Comment: What parameters?

Comment: For Schema Registry settings..

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Just a guess at what you are looking for...

```
kafka-avro-console-consumer --topic topicX --bootstrap-server kafka:9092 \ 
    --property schema.registry.url="http://schema-registry:8081"
```

No, you cannot specify a schema version. The ID is consumed directly from the Avro data in the topic. The subject name is mapped to the topic name.

Use `--property print.key=true` to see the Kafka message key. This is a general property of the regular console consumer.

These are the only extra options in the avro-console-consumer script, meaning other than what's already defined in `kafka-consumer-consumer`, you can only provide `--formatter` or `--property schema.registry.url`, and no other Schema Registry specific parameters (whatever those may be)

```sh
for OPTION in "$@"
do
  case $OPTION in
    --formatter)
      DEFAULT_AVRO_FORMATTER=""
      ;;
    --*)
      ;;
    *)
      PROPERTY=$OPTION
      case $PROPERTY in
        schema.registry.url*)
          DEFAULT_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL=""
        ;;
      esac
      ;;
    esac
done
```